# Verb for getting eggs from hens

Tags: verbs

"I am going to *milk* the cows, *shear* the sheep, and (*get the eggs from*) the hens."

Is there a simple verb for gathering eggs from hens?  If not, what's the most elegant way to say this?

Comment: You used two very fine candidates yourself: _get_ and _gather_. There is no single word for gathering eggs from the hen house, just like there is no single word for gathering mushrooms in a cave or picking blackberries in the woods.

Comment: @Janus 'there is no single word for gathering mushrooms in a cave or picking blackberries in the woods': you do realise you've probably opened the floodgates?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Although you **can** go *berrying*, that isn’t specific to blackberry-bearing bosques; *egging* is more about delivering eggs than about fetching them; and I believe *shrooming* may be something else altogether. :)  Oops, maybe I’m wrong: the OED for verb *egg* includes both a transitive “To pelt with (rotten) eggs” sense and an intransitive “To collect (wild fowls’) eggs” sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Lots of people go *blackberrying* every September in England, but not after Michaelmas Day (29th September), when the devil is said to spit on them.

Comment: Floodgate #2: There is also [*mushroom* ***hunting***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mushroom+gathering%2C+mushroom+hunting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmushroom%20gathering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmushroom%20hunting%3B%2Cc0). But it seems that *gathering mushrooms* is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gathering+mushrooms%2Chunting+mushrooms&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgathering%20mushrooms%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chunting%20mushrooms%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: **Eggstract**, of course.

Comment: A poultry farmer could be said to be *harvesting* the eggs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several verbs one can use figuratively:
• *[shake down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shake_down)*, with “To get money from someone using threats” and  “To search exhaustively” among others; so  *Now I’m going to go shake down the chickens* would imply going to gather eggs.
• *[burgle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burgle#Verb)* or *[burglarize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burglarize#Verb)*, “To commit burglary”.  Eg, *Now I’m going to go burglarize the chickens* would imply taking eggs from chickens.
• Also consider verbs *[plunder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plunder#Verb)* (“To take (goods) by pillage”), *[poach](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poach#Verb_2)* (“to take anything illegally or unfairly”), and *[dispossess](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dispossess#Verb)* (“To deprive someone of the possession of land” etc)
• *[rob](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rob#Verb)*, suggested in bishop's comment, looks like an excellent choice.  Senses shown in [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rob#Verb) include phrases like “To steal from”, “To deprive of”,  “To burgle”, and “To take possession of”. Eg, *Now I’m going to rob the chickens* or *Now I’m going to rob the chickens of their eggs*.

Comment: +1 Fun answer. I'm sure the hens do feel that they're bring burgled. If looks could kill, I'd be dead. Luckily for me, beaks do not. Excuse me, time to shake down the chickens.

Comment: A win for answering the question in its context - or at least giving it a good go.  I want to tell people I'm going to ___ the chickens.  I think "plunder the chickens" is fun, burgle is hilarious, and poach almost sounds right entirely.

Comment: I have both bees and chickens on my farm.  We *rob* bees, so I might as well *rob* the chickens, too!

Comment: Unfortunately *poaching eggs* is something you do in a kitchen, not a henhouse.

Comment: These suggestions are fun, playful, fanciful ways of describing the action.  None of them are common or ordinary words for it.  In the right context, using these could be fun; but when context isn’t clear, many of these might be difficult for listeners/readers to understand.

Answer (score 22):

No, there is not, since one does not extract eggs from a hen, as one does milk from a cow, nor is any specific work (usually described with a verb) involved, such as *shearing* the sheep, *gutting* a deer (also known as field dressing), or helping to *kid* a goat.

The verbs associated with eggs are *gather* and *collect*. You can *squeeze* the chicken, but it won't help.

Comment: Not even _unscramble_?

Comment: Apparently *birding, berrying,* and *egging* are things done in the wild, not in captivity.

Comment: @tchrist - Cool! But in the US at least, *egging* is often used to mean *throwing eggs at*. One should not *egg* a chicken.

Comment: You cannot gather an egg without breaking some omelettes. (Or something like that.)

Comment: What? not *deovulate?*

Comment: I already said, above to Janus, that *egging* was more in the delivering and in the receiving. I then looked it up and found an intransitive sense.